# When I log to the Laravel Stack Channel, where does the information go?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Laravel 5.6 documentation suggests the  configuration below.  When I post to this as follows, where does the data go?  How can I look at it?  Does this post go to both the slack and syslog channels and go to two separate places?

```
// Suggested log action    
Log::stack(['single', 'slack'])->info('Something happened!');


 // Suggested logging configuration
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['syslog', 'slack'],
    ],

    'syslog' => [
        'driver' => 'syslog',
        'level' => 'debug',
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'username' => 'Laravel Log',
        'emoji' => ':boom:',
        'level' => 'critical',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

laravel5.6 integrates the monolog ,and give u different choices to log the log . u use the stack and it means that u collect both the slack and syslog into the single channel stack, u can know it from the documents for laravel5.6

Comment: Are you saying that **(A)** when you post to stack, it goes to slack and syslog; or  are you saying that **(B)** when you post to slack and syslog, it goes to stack?